# Using tags on the products page

Tags: navigation, tabs, toggle, tagging, product

I have a question about the products page navigation. At this moment it is sorted in the tabs f.e. vendor, kit, performance etc. When you open the vendors tab there is categorization by the vendors name or by the kits name. Some vendors could have the same kit name or the same performance.

Now I would like to change it to the tagging navigation. I would like to include all of the tags above the products list or on the side to toggle the products with that particular tag, because users might not know the names of all kits or vendors or about performance to search for.

What do you suggest in this case, actually do you think that tagging is good for this kind of navigating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm right in thinking this is an ecomm site - you must tag up products, it's a standard practice.

Tags in eCommerce are called 'product attributes'. These attributes are what is used for the internal search on your site and for SEO.

It sounds like you would like to create a left-hand navigation bar to your product listing page, this is also an industry standard. The more attributes/tags you have the better, this makes for a more efficient on-site search experience.

A little tip for attributes - call them both the official name of the product and the slang term as these are the terms your users will be inputting.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that having tags is a good thing for search. Also it is good for seo. Even stackoverflow has the tags for each and every questions, but the main issue is we don't know about all the tags.

The same thing challenges us while creating a usable product search, so it's better to put the tags either on top of product list or creating a side bar with all tags.

**Wait**!! What if you have a lot of tags? Then it won't be a good idea to put all the tags. It's just better to put **top** 5 or 10 tags and a search option guiding users how to **search** a tag.